# Why does the compiler say there is an uncreachable catch block?

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm trying to use a try block for the first time while opening a file in a method. I use a scanner to read the words in the file into an ArrayList, and then I return a random word from this list. The problem is, when I compile, the compiler says that there is an unreachable catch block. I'm unsure if this is caused by the code itself, or if it's caused by where I put my return statements. Do I put the code that opens the file in the try block and leave the code that returns the randomly selected string after the catch blocks? Or do I put both the file code and the code that returns the string in the try block?

```
public String loadPuzzle() {
    try {
        ArrayList<String> puzzles = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Categories.txt"));
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            puzzles.add(line);
        }
        sc.close();
        //do i do the return statement here or after the try and catch blocks?
        int r = new Random().nextInt(puzzles.size() + 1);
        return puzzles.get(r);
    } 
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("The file was not found.");
        return "";
      // do i need to return a value in the catch blocks?
    }
    //the compiler throws the warning here: unreachable catch clause and FileNotFoundException already found
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you've written can't throw an IOException other than FileNotFoundException, so there can't be any exceptions to catch in that block.

Comment: You may want to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) in order to be absolutely sure that an exception doesn't get in the way of closing your `Scanner`.

Comment: Okay, so the return statements are in the right spot? I just have to get rid of the IOException? And also the try-with-resources would make sure to close the file at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is absolutely right. The second catch clause is unreachable because your code can't throw an `IOException` other than `FileNotFoundException`.

It is not really relevant where you put the second part of your code. I prefer putting it in the catch clause.

And you don't need to put a `return` statement in the catch clause but you can when it returns something like an error code. I would have just put a return at the end of the method

Answer (score 0):

Because the highest exception that will be thrown from your try block is `FileNotFoundException` so there is no point of catching `IOException` after `FileNotFoundException`